# Import HTML files into Confluence

Tags: confluence

I have a bunch of html files that I exported from fogbugz using their API, and I am trying to import them into Confluence using the UWC.

However when I try to import them, they are being imported in the html format and it looks like this in my space:

```
<p > </p><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="MsoNormalTable"     style="width:6.25in;border:rgb(230,229,229) 1pt outset;border-width:1pt;border-style:outset;border-color:rgb(230,229,229);"><tbody ><tr ><td style="width:150pt;vertical-align:top;border:rgb(230,229,229) 1pt inset;border-width:1pt;border-style:inset;border-color:rgb(230,229,229);background-color:rgb(67,93,141);"><b >Name: </b><br /></td><td style="border:rgb(230,229,229) 1pt inset;border-width:1pt;border-style:inset;border-color:rgb(230,229,229);">OEM engineer builds an application prototype using Connect<br /></td></tr><tr ><td style="width:150pt;vertical-align:top;border:rgb(230,229,229) 1pt inset;border-width:1pt;border-style:inset;border-color:rgb(230,229,229);background-color:rgb(67,93,141);"><b >Maturity (1, 2, Final): </b><br /></td><td style="border:rgb(230,229,229) 1pt inset;border-width:1pt;border-style:inset;border-color:rgb(230,229,229);">2<br /></td></tr><tr ><td style="width:150pt;vertical-align:top;border:rgb(230,229,229) 1pt inset;border-width:1pt;border-style:inset;border-color:rgb(230,229,229);background-color:rgb(67,93,141);"><b >Summary: </b><br />
```

Instead of looking like how it looked in the source wiki.

Any help with how to move forward would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Importing+Data+from+FogBugz+On+Demand which explains how to import wiki pages from other wikis? This of course depends on your wiki version, and the result may be sub-optiomal. What we normally do (< 10 pages):

- Go to the original page.
- Select all, copy.
- Go to Confluence, create page, paste.
- See the result, and correct if something is wrong.
- Don't forget the title.

This needs only 30 seconds per page, and if there  are not too much links, it is faster that any automatic version.